# Edit dynamic table row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to edit the form that created dynamically. but when I checked the checkbox(s), fill the form and click Edit button, only edited contents show up. The rests are all gone.

The table:

```
<table class="table" id="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Product</th>
     <th>Qty</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Inputs, Add and Edit buttons:

```
<input type="text" name="product" id="p" />
<input type="text" name="qty" id="q" />
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" id="edit">edit</button>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
  var product = $('#p').val();
  var qty = $('#q').val();
  data = 'product='+product+'&qty='+qty+'&action=add';
  $.ajax({
    url:'add.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:data,
    success:function(data){
        $('#list tbody').prepend(data);
    }
 });
});
$('#edit').click(function(){
  var product = $('#p').val();
  var qty = $('#q').val();
  data = 'product='+product+'&qty='+qty+'&action=edit';
  $.ajax({
    url:'edit.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:data,
    success:function(data){
        $('#list tbody').html(data);
    }
 });
 });
});
</script>
```

add.php

```
if($_POST['action']=='add'){
$p=$_POST["product"];
$q=$_POST["qty"];
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$p.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$q.'</td>';
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

edit.php

```
if($_POST['action']=='edit'){
$p=$_POST["product"];
$q=$_POST["qty"];
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$p.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$q.'</td>';
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

I think I should assign an id to `echo '<tr id="x">'` but I don't know how.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

John